# What coordinate system does this map use? How to convert it into latitude and longitude?

Tags: coordinate-system, trimble

What coordinate system does this map use: https://kartat.espoo.fi/ims ?` See the "P" and "I" in the bottom right corner. Based on the Trimble logo at the bottom right corner as well, it's some kind of solution built with Trimble

How would I convert these "coordinates" into normal latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has to be the Finnish Gauss-Krüger zone 25 https://epsg.org/crs_3879/ETRS89-GK25FIN.html?

So nothing that is specific to Trimble. The Trimble logo stands at the corner just because they seem to use Trimble services for the web map https://upa.trimble.com/en-eu.

You can convert the coordinates with your favorite software.
Example with gdaltransform https://gdal.org/programs/gdaltransform.html

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:3879 -t_srs epsg:4326
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
25485308 6675757
24.7351469525604 60.1943627146485 0
```

Notice that for gdaltransform you must change the order of North (P) and East (I) coordinates. The result in EPSG:4326 is printed in longitude-latitude order.